# How to upload APK to Saucelabs

Tags: selenium, appium, saucelabs

I want to upload my APK to Saucelabs, How can I do that?

Is there any tab do so ?

I am trying with Curl command as well, which is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, U have to use curl command correctly.

Use below Link to download curl :
http://curl.haxx.se/download.html

After that use below curl command :
curl -u YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME:YOUR_SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" https://saucelabs.com/rest/v1/storage/YOUR_SAUCE_USERNAME/YOUR_ANDROID_APP.apk